# how to add main method to Visual C++/CLR/Class Library?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Last 10 years I was only using C#/Java so sorry about my simple questions about c++.

Now I've to add one c++ project to my solution. I do not need to be it standalone application, I need it to do some work and to transfer result to my another c# project. So I've created "Visual C++ / CLR / Class Library".

By default such project doesn't contain too much code. Just this:

```
// CliProject.h file
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace CliProject {

public ref class Class1
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
};
}


// CliProject.cpp file
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CliProject.h"
```

Now for debugging I want to add "main" method so I can launch my library as standalone application. How to do that? Should I create one another class or I should use existent classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 'CLR Console Application' project with a reference to your library. Or even better, for debugging, use a unit test framework.

Comment: But will I be able to add "CLR Console Application" as a reference to my C# project?

Comment: I thought you were trying to debug your CLR class library. There should be no connection with your C# proj. They are independent consumers of the library

Comment: I see. Well the same way I can add some "debug" code to my C# proj. I was thinking of adding debug code to clr library itself. So I can actually launch CLR library itself. Probably this is not possible.

Comment: It's possible.... but it would then have to become an executable. You can consume an executable in .net as a library but in this case it's a pretty weird way of going about things if you ask me.